# Windows apps DatagridView header column pop menu for data filtering

Tags: c#-3.0

Good Day!

How to add a textbox pop-up menu when I right click on Datagridview Header column?
This is for data filtering.

Any help?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly what you asked for, but should help with some of the core concepts:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480727.aspx